# Split a series on time gaps in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to split a time series on it's gaps. For example, suppose we had the following:

```
rng2011 = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
rng2012 = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=72, freq='H')
Y = rng2011.union(rng2012)
```

Is it possible to look for gaps of a year or more, and split the data frame on them?

I imagine this would go something like:

```
Y.groupby(Y.map(lambda x: x.year))
```

Except that this splits on the year date, and I'm interested in specifying an interval gap rather than the year attribute of the row.

The application is I've got trip logs from a gps, but no delineation of when one trip ended and another began. I'd like to split on gaps of ten minutes or longer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming Y is a column in your dataframe, one way is to use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and [cumsum](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df = DataFrame(Y)
df[1] = df[0].diff() > 600000000000.0 #nanoseconds in ten minutes
df[1] = df[1].cumsum()
df.groupby(1)
```

*Note: If you use the number of nanoseconds in 72 hours it'll split into two groups.*

Comment: thanks, that works nicely! Can you also do the same with Y as an index?

Comment: does this work on 0.10.0? col 1 contains the range 0..143 on my system.

Comment: @crewbum that's because the dataset is separated by hour (so they all split...)!

Comment: does it make sense for diff() on a datetime64 series to return a float64 series, while ``df[0][1] - df[0][0]`` returns a datetime.timedelta object?

Comment: @Maus a lazy solution: `df[0] = df.index`... :s

Comment: @hayden definitely did that :)

Comment: diff returns timedelta objects now in pandas master.

Comment: ... or, diff() will soon return timedelta: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3100

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye @crewburn Does it? I can still do this same thing in latest master... ('0.11.0.dev-184f2db'). `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=3, freq='H')); df[0].diff()[1] == 3600000000000.0`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. But *NOW* it's working (fixed 7 days ago by the glorious Jeff). Just tried it with 0.12.0.dev-f354548.

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye Hurray! Good work Jeff (as always)! So it should land in 0.11.1 then :)

Comment: You could also use datetime.timedelta to express gap in larger units: df[1] = df[0].diff() > timedelta(minutes=10)